# ExtJS 4.2 How can I get all the stores of a view?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I´m trying to obtain all the stores of a view in a controller. For example my view is a panel that has 2 grids and 4 combos,every one has his own store.
Is there a way to obtain all the stores using Ext.ComponentQuery or something like this.Ext.StoreManager returns all the stores of the app,I only want the stores of a specific view.

Comment: There's nothing built in, you would need to manage it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a component that does have a store that is not bound using the `store` property, bad luck. But if you are only working with basic ExtJS components like grid and combo, you may try whether

```
view.query("[store]").map(function(cmp) {return cmp.getStore() });
```

does what you want...

Comment: Thank you,thas was what I need